# Running stable-diffusion on graphcore IPU's

Tags: pytorch, torch, ipu

I have been looking for a version of Stable-Diffusion which would be able to run on the IPU's. Currently (due to the high availability) so far I can find CUDA based ones only.

Now I wonder if there is a way to run scripts/trainers/learning etc that are Cuda based on IPU? For example a translation program in between.

I doubt there is, and I bet as I cannot find a IPU version I'll have to modify the scripts :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the [HuggingFace optimum](https://github.com/huggingface/optimum-graphcore) library which acts as the interoperability layer for transformers to run on IPUs. You can find [Stable Diffusion](https://github.com/huggingface/optimum-graphcore/tree/main/notebooks/stable_diffusion) there.

For other models that are not supported in the library, there's a guide on how you could modify your script to make it IPU-compatible [here](https://github.com/huggingface/optimum-graphcore/blob/main/notebooks/external_model.ipynb)